# kohana 3.0.12 how to log

Tags: php, exception, kohana, kohana-3

i am working on an website on kohana 3.0.12 and i have installed a module that loggs me some errors. All works fine, except that, when i want to effectively log an error, i get an error and i don;t know how to manage it.

Here is the messy code:

```
public static function handler(Exception $e)
{


    // It's a nice time to log :)
    Kohana::$log->add(Kohana::ERROR, Kohana_Exception::text($e));

    etc code here
```

well that Kohana_Exception::text($e) causes an exception like:  Call to undefined method Kohana_Exception::text() ? i guess it is a framework bug. any idea of how i can solve the problem? (i guess i should use another instance but Kohana_Exception:: but what instance?)
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because neither `Kohana_Exception` nor `Exception` classes don't have `text()` method. I think the author of the module wanted to write like this:

```
Kohana::$log->add(Kohana::ERROR, Kohana::exception_text($e));
```

Comment: works perfect now, but i have one error left at the end of the exception: 

echo Request::factory(Route::get('kohana_error')->uri($request))
    ->execute()
    ->send_headers()
    ->body();
this code throws me Call to undefined method Request::body() any idea why?

Comment: body() was introduced in 3.2, for 3.0 I believe you should use `Request::factory(Route::get('kohana_error')->uri($request)) ->execute() ->send_headers() ->response;`

Comment: problem solved. one (more) problem left: it actually doesn't log this kind of errors in the log location (declared in the bootstrap). any hints ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I belive the exception handling in 3.0 is located in the Kohana class. Try Kohana::exception(), or look in api guide if that isn't it.